# Drawing 3D regions (regions of integration)

Tags: diagrams

Is there any straightforward/easy way of drawing regions of integration or should I not bother with LaTeX and simply create the image from another program?

Sample:

[image: Eqn 1]

(bounded by x=0, y=0, z=0 and x+y+z=1)

[image: Triangle]

[image: Eqn 2]

(bounded by z=0, z=2, x=0, y=2 and y=x^2)

[image: Slice]

[image: Eqn 3]

(bounded by z=0, x+y=1, x=0, z=sqrt(y))

[image: Complex]

Comment: Hint: `pst-solides3d`

Comment: Please try to do something by yourself and then add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to your post. As is, your question is a just-do-it-for-me one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 3d-coordinates in tikz. It is not a 3d model, just three vectors in a 2d picture, but it can be quite handy.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=(-150:1cm),y=(-30:1cm),z=(90:1cm)]
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=30]{$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=150]{$y$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=-90]{$z$};
  %%
  \draw[red,fill=gray!30](0,0,0) -- (1,0,0)-- (0,0,1) -- cycle;
  \draw[red,fill=gray!30](0,0,0) -- (0,1,0)-- (0,0,1) -- cycle;
  \draw[red,fill=gray!30](0,0,0) -- (1,0,0)-- (0,1,0) -- cycle;
  \draw[red,fill=gray!30,opacity=0.5](1,0,0) -- (0,1,0)-- (0,0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=(-150:1cm),y=(-30:1cm),z=(90:1cm)]
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=30]{$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=150]{$y$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=-90]{$z$};
  %%
  \draw[red,fill=gray!30,opacity=0.5](0,0,0) plot[domain=0:1,samples=10,smooth] (\x,\x*\x,0) -- (0,1,0) -- cycle;
  \draw[red,fill=gray!30,opacity=0.5](0,0,0) plot[domain=0:1,samples=10,smooth] (\x,\x*\x,0) -- (1,1,0.3) plot[domain=1:0,samples=10,smooth] (\x,\x*\x,0.3) -- (0,0,0);
  \draw[red,fill=gray!30,opacity=0.5] (1,1,0) -- (0,1,0) -- (0,1,0.3) -- (1,1,0.3) -- cycle;
  \draw[red,fill=gray!30,opacity=0.5] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) -- (0,1,0.3) -- (0,0,0.3) -- cycle;
  \draw[red,fill=gray!30,opacity=0.5](0,0,0.3) plot[domain=0:1,samples=10,smooth] (\x,\x*\x,0.3) -- (0,1,0.3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=(-150:1cm),y=(-30:1cm),z=(90:1cm)]
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1.5,0,0) node[anchor=30]{$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.5,0) node[anchor=150]{$y$};
  \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.5) node[anchor=-90]{$z$};
  %%
  \newcommand\start{0.03}
  \draw[red,fill=gray!30,opacity=0.5] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) -- (0,1,0) -- cycle;
  \draw[red,fill=gray!30,opacity=0.5] (0,0,0) plot[domain=0:1,samples=100,variable=\y,smooth] (0,\y,{0.5*sqrt(\y)}) -- (0,1,0) -- cycle;
  \draw[red,fill=gray!30,opacity=0.5] (1,0,0) plot[domain=0:1,samples=100,smooth] (1-\x,\x,{0.5*sqrt(\x)}) -- (0,1,0) -- cycle;
  \fill[fill=gray!30,opacity=0.5] (1-\start,\start,{0.5*sqrt(\start)}) plot[domain=\start:1,samples=100,smooth] (1-\x,\x,{0.5*sqrt(\x)})  plot[domain=1:\start,samples=100,variable=\y,smooth] (0,\y,{0.5*sqrt(\y)}) -- (1-\start,\start,{0.5*sqrt(\start)});
  \draw[red] (1,0,0) plot[domain=0:1,samples=100,smooth] (1-\x,\x,{0.5*sqrt(\x)})  plot[domain=1:\start,samples=100,variable=\y,smooth] (0,\y,{0.5*sqrt(\y)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is rather straightforward to do this with asymptote. Here is an example.

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
 \begin{document}
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \begin{asy}
 import three;

 size(200);

 currentprojection=perspective(4,5,5);

 // axes
 real r=1.5;
 draw(Label("$x$",1), O--r*X, Arrow3(HookHead3));
 draw(Label("$y$",1), O--r*Y, Arrow3(HookHead3));
 draw(Label("$z$",1), O--r*Z, Arrow3(HookHead3));

 draw(X--Y--Z--X--O--Y--O--Z,red);
 \end{asy}
 \end{document}
```

[image]